Finding $\sin(\alpha-30^\circ)$, where $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha$ is in the 2nd quadrant, without a calculator

Given that $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha$ is in the 2nd quadrant, find without using the calculator's trigonometric functions the value of $\sin(\alpha-30^\circ)$.

First, I calculated the value of $\tan\alpha$ using $\tan\alpha=\frac{2\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}}{1-\tan^2\frac{\alpha}{2}}=\frac{4}{3}$, but since $\alpha$ is in the 2nd quadrant it should be $-\frac{4}{3}$.
Next, I calculated $\cos^2\alpha$: $1+\tan^2\alpha=\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}$ and the result is $\cos\alpha=-\frac{3}{5}$. Once again, the result is negative since the angle is in the 2nd quadrant.
Now I can calculate $\sin\alpha$ by using the identity $\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha=1$ and I get $\sin\alpha=\frac{4}{5}$.
Finally I can calculate $\sin(\alpha-30^\circ)$:
$$\sin(\alpha-30^\circ)=\sin\alpha \cos30^\circ-\sin30^\circ\cos\alpha=\frac{4}{5}\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{3}{5})=0.9982$$
This seemed to be right, but when I went from the end backwards in order to verify the result, I got that $\sin^{-1}0.9982=86.56^\circ$ or $93.43^\circ$, so $\alpha-30^\circ =86.56^\circ \to\alpha=116.56^\circ\to\frac{\alpha}{2}=58.28^\circ$, but $\tan58.28^\circ=1.61$ and not $\frac{1}{2}$ as given. Using the second result $(\alpha=93.43^\circ)$ does not give $\frac{1}{2}$ either.
Also, $\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}=26.56^\circ \to\alpha=53.13^\circ$ and $\alpha$ is in the first quadrant.
Where was I wrong?

The problem has no solution. Since $\frac\pi2<\alpha<\pi$, $\frac\pi4<\frac\alpha2<\frac\pi2$, and therefore $\tan\left(\frac\alpha2\right)>1$.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your time. Didn't think about this approach... Unfortunately it was an exam question and my nephew wasted more than 30 minutes trying to solve it. Tried to solve it myself and got contradiction.

Your nephew probably did not report to you correctly the statement of his exercise.

@AnneBauval One of his classmates took picture of the exem.

Excellent! Can you please include this picture in your post?

@AnneBauval It's in Hebrew, so I don't think it will be helpful.

Hint: If $\tan (\alpha/2) = 1/2$, it must be positive in the first and third quadrants.  That means it cannot be positive in the second quadrant - only $\sin (\alpha/2)$ is.  Hence, this is impossible, and thus $\sin (\alpha - 30°)$ has no solution.

If $\tan \frac {\alpha}{2}=\frac {1}{2}$, this value and $\tan \alpha$ will be positive in the first and third quadrants.  For the second quadrant, only $\sin \alpha$ is positive, so the two solutions you got for $\sin (\alpha - 30°)$ were extraneous. Hence, you will have no solutions for $\sin (\alpha - 30°)$ for $\tan \frac {\alpha}{2}=\frac {1}{2}$.
Also, Jose Carlos Santos's hint confirms that while $90° \lt \alpha \lt 180°$, taking the half angle will give you $45° \lt \frac {\alpha}{2} \lt 90°$, and $\tan \frac {\alpha}{2}$ increases from $1$ to $\infty$ in that range.
